# Automatic spam detector?

Tags: discussion, spam

I'm seeing more and more 1 reputation user creating high quality spam referring to mag-manager.com .

Is there any way we can have something like an automatic spam detector based on the content of the post. Something that would delete the posts that contain mag-manager.com links and ban the user ?

Edit: Ended up writing my own spam detectiong query for them: https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/567921/posts-with-many-thank-you-answers

Comment: I don't think this can be added to the spam filter, as theoretically that extension is as valid as any other extension. The problem is just with the way the answer is formed. And by the way, you just helped their spam campain by posting ...you know...their website name. :)

Comment: @Marius yeah I also called them out on Twitter to ask them to stop. I'm happy to flag them manually I was just wondering if there's some automatic thing available in SO as sometimes there is a little "our system detected this post as potential spam" above some post review and this message does not show up for those posts

Comment: There are some spam filters, but the posts don't look like spam filters if you ignore the words and the links. I really hope there is a way to stop these. I an annoyed by them also, but I don't have a solution. That's why I added a comment and not an answer. I don't have access to the spam filter (and I shouldn't)

Comment: @Marius yeah I think i'm just gonna contact them directly, I'm just trying to get some info about their company first so see how "legit" they are

Comment: @Marius there's a lot we missed: https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/567921/posts-with-many-thank-you-answers

Comment: An unsolicited opinion from an outsider: Certain things can be [blacklisted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/allow-adding-a-specific-message-guidance-to-blacklists). For this specific case, if it is a problem and the community decides it's a good idea, you could request this domain receive that treatment from a community manager.

Comment: If you cannot get the target blacklisted by site admins, there is a StackExchange-wide anti-spam volunteer effort which runs a bot where an alert rule could easily be implemented, but it's not entirely clear from your SEDE query which precise results from that query we should target. If you'd like to set something up, links to, or excerpts from, example posts might be a good start. There is a [presentation page](https://charcoal-se.github.io/) and if you want to get in touch, the [Charcoal chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) is where bot development happens.

Comment: @Marius any way you can check the links tripleee posted ?

Comment: will do, but I don't have the time right now.

Comment: @Marius sure np thank you

Comment: Just a few example links should suffice for us to take it from there, but if you'd like to participate or coordinate further, the links will hopefully help get you on board.  This comment thread is probably not a good place for example links, so perhaps the easiest way forward would be to set up an informal chat room for quick coordination.

Comment: @tripleee I'm off today I'll set that up tomorrow and provide some example links ;)

Comment: Chat happened: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33266506#33266506

Comment: Further reports of suspected spam on this site will be sent to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47869/charcoal-smokedetector-reports

Comment: @Marius The [chat room](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47869) mentioned in comments here and in Raphael's answer has been frozen for 627 days. However, we still have it configured in SmokeDetector to report detected Magento posts in that room. I'm happy for us to leave the chat room configuration in SmokeDetector, but it doesn't appear to be doing people any good (based on how long it's been frozen). Is there a more appropriate room, or is it better for us to not have a room where Magento posts are separately reported (they will continue to be reported in the rooms where all spam is reported)?

Comment: @Makyen. I don't think there is a need for a separate room. Fewer things to manage. :).

Comment: @Marius OK. Thanks. Sounds reasonable. I'll take the room out of the configuration file. If at some point in the future you desire to have Magento posts reported into a room, please feel free to contact us, either here or in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq).

Comment: sure. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, thanks to @tripleee comment I ended up contacting Charcoal directly via the dedicated chat room.

The transcript is here if you wanna check it out: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33266506#33266506

So after discussing with them, they've added alerts for Magento SE:

- GitHub Issue: https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/issues/277
- PR: https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/pull/276 and https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/pull/278

So from now on, **every post containing mag-manager.com for users with up to 50 reputation will be flagged** and automatically sent to this dedicated Chat Room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47869/charcoal-smokedetector-reports

Answer (score 3):

Charcoal has brought the SmokeDetector to the next level. See this meta post: [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically)

You can now sign up and make your SE account available for flagging spam. SmokeDetector will raise spam flags on your name through the API. The data that they have collected over the years enables them to provide a very high accuracy in the automated system, higher than human flagging ;)